# Switching to bundled Java runtime for PyCharm(Manjaro)?

Tags: java, python, pycharm, manjaro

I'm running PyCharm on Manjaro(latest version of both) and upon starting PyCharm, a prompt appears that says I should "Please consider switching to the bundled Java runtime that is better suited for your IDE(your current Java runetime is 11.0.11+9 by Oracle Corp. at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk"

I've tried choosing different runtimes using Ctrl+Shift+A but none of them stop this prompt from appearing. Is this something I should worry about or should I brush it off?

New to both Python and Manjaro so not really sure how to proceed. Unable to find anything pertaining to this issue on this distro.

Edit: I downloaded the most recent version(11.0.12) and adding it as a custom runtime, but for some reason it shows that I'm still using the aforementioned version...

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Run `$ PYCHARM_JDK=/path/to/runtime/ pycharm`

If you installed PyCharm through the package manager (e.g. pacman), the launcher will be installed to someplace like /usr/bin/pycharm. This is basically a shell script that sets the JDK for PyCharm before calling the main executable. When the environment variable `PYCHARM_JDK` is not set, it defaults to a system Java 11 JDK.

Changing the boot runtime within PyCharm doesn't change this script. You'll need to set `PYCHARM_JDK` from the command line, in your .bashrc, or by editing /usr/bin/pycharm. Use Help -> About to confirm that the expected runtime was selected.

As for which runtime to use, `jbr_jcef-11_0_11-linux-x64-b1341.60` works nicely on my machine. The JetBrains support forum will have to explain what the differences are.